# How to push footer at the bottom and center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the Made with love text at the bottom fixed but also at the center. And it is not getting center if am doing  `position: fixed`

```
        <header>
            <h1>Color Changer</h1>
            <hr width= 500px>
        </header>
        <main>
            <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#E6E6E6">
            <input class="color2" type="color"name="color2">
        </main>
        <footer>
            <h2>This Website Color Changes</h2>
            <p>Made with love</p>
        </footer>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is my style.css

```
    padding-top: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}
header {
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
h1 {
    transition: transform 1s;
}
h1:hover {
    transform: translate(20px,20px);
}
footer p {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
footer {
    text-align: center!important;
}
```

After doing this the p element gets fixed at the bottom but doesn't align to the center.
I want the position to be bottom but not fixed.

Comment: Frankly, `position:fixed` should be on the **footer** not the contents of that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fixed` for an HTML block element, it loses its implicit `width: 100%`
So you must do

```
footer p {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin: 0 auto and text-align: center to the p. They are used for putting the element at center.
Margin: 0 auto is shorthand for margin left and right equal and margin top and bottom 0. If you want a different top and bottom margin add something like margin: 20px auto.

Comment: It's not going to work, because text-align will be applied to it's children and not itself, and since <p> is less than the width of the page nothing will be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `<p>` element `100%` width:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}

header {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

h1 {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

h1:hover {
  transform: translate(20px, 20px);
}

footer p {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  text-align: center!important;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Color Changer</h1>
  <hr width=5 00px>
</header>
<main>
  <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#E6E6E6">
  <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2">
</main>
<footer>
  <h2>This Website Color Changes</h2>
  <p>Made with love</p>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```